# winium implicit wait is not working

Tags: wait, implicit, winium

I'm trying to check implicit wait functionality in winium but application is getting freeze while executing the below step.

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have already received an answer to this, but here is what I did and it worked for me. It is similar to what you already have just updated some.

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```